# R: for-loop over matrix returns only last values

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, caching, iteration

So I have a matrix filled with random numbers: `mat_base = matrix(sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow=10, ncol=10)` and another matrix `mat_table = matrix(,100,3)` which has the column names: `colnames(mat_table) <- c("row", "col", "value")`.

I want to put all values and their locations (row and column numbers) from `mat_base` to `mat_table` and I have already succeeded doing so with the locations. But for the values for each cell `mat_table` only returns the values from the last column of `mat_base`.

This is the code I have so far:

```
for (j in 1:nrow(mat_base)) {
  for (k in 1:ncol(mat_base)){ 
    #2 nested for-loops to go through mat_base
    
    mat_table[,1] <- row(mat_base)
    #the function "row" returns a matrix of row numbers
    #put row numbers in the first column of mat_table
    
    mat_table[,2] <- col(mat_base)
    #the function "col" returns a matrix of column numbers
    #put column numbers in the second column of mat_table
    
    mat_table[,3] <- mat_base[,k]
    #get current value of mat_base and put it into mat_table
    #put values in the third column of mat_table

  }
  
}

mat_table
#show mat_table in the console
```

I know that I might not need the outer for-loop with `j` because the result is the same without it (I'm not using `j` anyways) but I wasn't sure so I left it in for now.

This is the reult I am getting with this code:

```
> mat_table
       row col value
  [1,]   1   1     4
  [2,]   2   1    11
  [3,]   3   1    13
  [4,]   4   1    13
  [5,]   5   1     2
  [6,]   6   1    17
  [7,]   7   1     7
  [8,]   8   1    14
  [9,]   9   1    19
 [10,]  10   1     3
 [11,]   1   2     4
 [12,]   2   2    11
 [13,]   3   2    13
 [14,]   4   2    13
 [15,]   5   2     2
 [16,]   6   2    17
 [17,]   7   2     7
 [18,]   8   2    14
 [19,]   9   2    19
 [20,]  10   2     3
 [21,]   1   3     4
 [22,]   2   3    11
 [23,]   3   3    13
...
```

As you can see in the third column of `mat_table` only the last column of `mat_base` is repeated over and over again. How can I get all values from `mat_base` into `mat_table`?

**Edit/Answer:**
Okay I found out that by using loops I made my life a lot harder than it had to be...
This is how I solved this problem in the end:

```
mat_base = matrix(sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow=10, ncol=10) 
#my data

mat_table = matrix(,100,3)
#create an empty matrix with 100 rows and 3 columns
colnames(mat_table) <- c("row", "col", "value")
#change the column names 

mat_table <- cbind(c(row(mat_base)), c(col(mat_base)), c(mat_base))
#put row numbers, column numbers and values from mat_base into mat_table

mat_table
#show mat_table in console
```

**Edit 2:**
But if you want to do it the way I was trying initially, check the answer from @Mohanasundaram!

Comment: Look carefully at your loop, and run some lines individually. See how your `mat_table` has 100 rows, and `mat_base` has only 10? That means R will *recycle* values of mat_base to fill the 100 rows. In your loop, you are overwriting the entire 3rd column with whatever loop iteration you are on, recycled to the length. So, the final iteration of your loop simply overwrites the entire 3rd column, which is why you are seeing this. Also, yes, the `j` loop is not needed. R is vectorized already. Nowhere in your code are you telling R to somehow stack the results, which is what you want.

Comment: @Adam thank you for your comments and the link, sadly I don't really understand what's going on there :( And for your other comment: I know that I'm constantly overwriting the third column but I don't know how to avoid that...

Comment: @Adam nvm I carefully looked over it again and now I understand what's going on! Thank you again for your comments and the link :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate way of getting the desired table is this.

```
mat_base = matrix(sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow=10, ncol=10)

mat_table <- data.frame(row = rep(1:nrow(mat_base), by = ncol(mat_base)),
                        col = rep(1:ncol(mat_base), each = nrow(mat_base)),
                        value = c(mat_base))
```

For your original method, this is the solution. You have to filter the matrix by row names and columns names and then assign the value. However, this is not an efficient way.

```
mat_base = matrix(sample(1:20, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow=10, ncol=10)
mat_table = matrix(,100,3)
colnames(mat_table) <- c("row", "col", "value")

for (j in 1:nrow(mat_base)) {
  for (k in 1:ncol(mat_base)){ 
    #2 nested for-loops to go through mat_base
    
    mat_table[,1] <- row(mat_base)
    #the function "row" returns a matrix of row numbers
    #put row numbers in the first column of mat_table
    
    mat_table[,2] <- col(mat_base)
    #the function "col" returns a matrix of column numbers
    #put column numbers in the second column of mat_table
    
    mat_table[mat_table[,"row"] == j & mat_table[,"col"] == k,3] <- mat_base[j,k]
    #get current value of mat_base and put it into mat_table
    #put values in the third column of mat_table
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! I'm still trying to figure out though why my loop only returns the last column and how to work around that.

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Comment: This helps so much, thank you! I liked the short code but I was really curious to find out how to do this using for-loops as well :)